# How to Parse Sitemap XML Content using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have site that is on wordpress. I want to make a PHP Script that will parse XML content from the URL and show me in the form of table.

I had written below PHP Script to parse the data

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($xml->url as $url)
{
    ?>
    Loc: <?php echo $url->loc; ?>
    <br />
    Last Modified: <?php echo $url->lastmod; ?>
    <br />
    Image Title: <?php echo $xml->children('image', true)->image->title; ?>
    <br />
    Image Location: <?php echo $xml->children('image', true)->image->loc; ?>
    <hr />
    <?php
}
?>
```

**Problem**
The Above PHP Script is working fine to parse Loc & Last Modified But **Not Working for Image Loc & Image Title.**
**Sitemap URL**

> `view-source:http://getintoblog.com/post-sitemap.xml`

**Kindly Help.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the structure of the XML document you can see that the `<image>` tags you are trying to parse are children of `<url>`, not `<xml>`.

Change `$xml->children('image', true)` to `$url->children('image', true)` in your code and you should be fine.